# How long will it take to get my api permission reviewed under the new policy?

Tags: instagram-api

I applied for the api permission under Instagram's new platform policy. How long will it take to get my application reviewed? I looked through the documents and could find any clue about how long I should wait.

Comment: Trying to find answer to the same question. Been waiting 5 days so far...

Comment: someone posted here saying it took 2 weeks and was rejected